# Tool/Library suggestions for collecting and analyzing log files from .Net WinForms app

Tags: .net, logs, log-analysis

I am developing an old WinForms app which generates three different log files, all with their own log format. All log entries has date/time, message (and possibly exception details).

My main purpose is to collect all three log files and being able to view an aggregated log, where at least all items appear in "timestamp order".

Requirements:

- Should integrate well with .Net, not necessary to access/view the aggregates logs from the client though.
- If possible, it would be nice if the "aggregated log viewer" could provide some analysis, eg color coding, timeline utilities, highlight exceptions, group log entries by time etc.
- Preferably small non-commercial libraries/tools. However open for all suggestions.

Thanks for your suggestions!